# Is there a way to prevent OSX .pkg deleting other dev versions?

Tags: pkgbuild

Exactly the same question has been asked 8 years ago at [OSX .pkg deletes other dev versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19779611/osx-pkg-deletes-other-dev-versions)

The answer was

> pkgbuild does not support not overwriting the previous version at this time

Is there any news or does the same restriction still apply today?

Answer (score 0):

According to this comment: [Mac installer overwrites ALL copies of file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51298643/mac-installer-overwrites-all-copies-of-file#comment89601311_51309611), setting `BundleIsRelocatable` to `FALSE` fixes this.